# Error "(424) Object required" when running VBScript as SYSTEM

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a service running as SYSTEM, which launches a VBScript to automate Microsoft Word.

The script runs fine under my own account on the server, but fails on the following line when running under SYSTEM. The line should just open a Word document template.

```
Set objTemplate = objWord.Documents.Open(sTemplate)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    debugFile.Write "Error: " & "(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    objWord.Quit 0
    WScript.Quit Err.Number
End If
```

On the previous line I added a check to ensure that objWord is not null - it seems ok.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Comment: is there an access rights difference between SYSTEM and your account?

Comment: thanks - well, SYSTEM is the built-in administrator account, so I imagine it should have everything it needs.

Comment: I doubt it will work on SYSTEM, Word when launched, it creates files in the user profile - have you seen a "SYSTEM" in Users folder?